Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.6.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.6.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.6.3')
Searched in the following repositories:
Google
MavenRepo
Gradle Central Plugin Repository


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

gradle-wraper-properties:


distributionUrl=file:///D:/down/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip



settings.gradle:



plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version '7.6.3' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.0" apply false
}

include ":app"



build.gradle:


buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.3'
    }
}


You're not actually asking a question, posting what you tried and are expecting to happen
